# Cannot scan QR code for WhatsApp web even when mobile data only

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-10, qr-code

I am on the very last version of WhatsApp for Android: it can't no longer connect to WhatsApp Web (it worked fine for ages)

I tried all older tricks found in this forum: mobile data only(no wifi), rotate QR code by 90°, clean up camera lens, etc. Nothing works

Does anybody have this issue as well?  What else should I try ?

My phone is a Samsung S10 (patched to very last firmware & Android)

Thanks for your help!

Didier

Comment: Please do mention the exact versions.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, my problem got solved : I got an update of WhatsApp on both my phone (2.20-2005.169 and my Mac (Version 2.2047.10). With those 2 versions, I can connect WhatsApp Web and WhatsApp Mac with my Samsung phone again.

NB: for it to work, you MUST on the phone use ...>WhatsApp Web and then scan the code even for the Mac App. Do NOT go  ...>Settings>QR code (top right)>Scan Code: you'll get a scanning error message saying *"Use the WhatsApp Web scanner to scan this QR code"*

I hope that it help others facing same problem.

Didier

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what NB said above, open whatsapp app on your mobile, tap on the 3 dots in the upper right corner, select "WhatsApp Web", then scan the QR code displayed on your computer with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue of screen brightness. Make sure that you're not using apps that can dim the screen or have it at full brightness.

Apps like deluminate and dark mode may affect the scans.
You can try adjusting your screen brightness/contrast till it can take the scan.

Comment: Hi! Can you please edit your answer to be more straight forward? Something to the effect of "This could be an issue of screen brightness. Make sure that you're not using apps that can dim the screen and have it at full brightness", but elaborate as you feel necessary. Remember these are potential solutions, not suggestions!